# vector tiles, mapbox style.json

Tags: mapbox, here-api, mapbox-gl

I'd like to use the [here maps vector tiles](https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/) in a [mapbox gl](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) app. However, in order to do so, I need to define a `style.json`, see [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/?q=protobuf&size=n_10_n) for the spec, and [here](https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json) for an example.

Does here have a base `style.json` that I can use?

On the [examples page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/topics/draw-a-map.html), where using Mapbox is discussed, the documentation simply says: `style: "map_style.json", // you should use your own style`. It's a bit of a PITA (pain in the a**) to build from scratch, though.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure why they don't write about `mapboxgl.accessToken` which required to use mapbox's style and map, it seems like you should create your own map and styles then insert `composite` source in the source of the style.

Comment: @ChaseChoi The Mapbox accessToken is only needed if you use Mapbox map tiles or some other resources from Mapbox styles. This case is for a 3rd party tile server.

Answer (score 0):

map_style.json -

```
this could be different for different use case and plain "JSON" file. This needs to be according to the map properties that needs to be displayed to use the other container style.
```

Comment: But can you publish a complete example style json? One that would make the layer look like the default styling in native HERE would be sufficient for majority of cases I'd say.